# Posting with Google+ API

Tags: java, android, google-plus

Is it possible to post to the users wall with the current G+ API? I've only been able to find info on getting information. Seems as if posting any data isn't currently supported.

Comment: Haven't used the G+ API myself, but that is consistent with what I've heard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information from https://developers.google.com/+/api/:

> Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if there were any work around methods anyone had been using to make it work. guess we are out of luck till google real eases a read/write API.